# OpenSSL implementation of improved SHA-1 hashing

Tags: c++, hash, openssl, sha1

Where can I find OpenSSL implementation of improved sha1 hashing based on 64 bit instruction set. It is an alternative implementation of [this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/improving-the-performance-of-the-secure-hash-algorithm-1/#comment-72104%20%27this%27). I tried to find it in my `/usr/inclusde` and `/usr/lib/` but could not get it. It seems it is an add-on to OpenSSL (`openssl-addons/intel-accel/`) but does not come with OpenSSL package. Also how to use it in place of OpenSSL 's usual SHA-1?

Comment: You might be interested in [Noloader | SHA-Intrinsics](https://github.com/noloader/SHA-Intrinsics) GitHub. The GitHub provides an intriniscs based implementation using SHA instructions that works on BSD, Linux, OS X and Windows.

Comment: If you are trying to incorporate only the assembly language routine for SHA-1, then take a look at [Cryptogams | AES](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Cryptogams_AES) on the OpenSSL wiki. Also see [How the assembly file is generated from the perl script in OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46322246/608639) on Stack Overflow. Both show you how to use the assembly language routine as stand-alone without the OpenSSL dependency.

Answer (score 3):

The SSE3-optimized version of SHA-1 is already part of `OpenSSL 1.0.1`, no need for add-ons. Just make sure that you compile it with assembler routines (not generic C).

Just for your reference: the optimized implementation of SHA-1 is in files `crypto/sha/asm/sha1-586.pl` and `crypto/sha/asm/sha1-x86_64.pl` in the openssl 1.0.1 tarball.